# How to have numlock enabled on login screen without disabling fast startup?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen, numlock

**Problem**

I can't get `numlock` enabled by default on `login screen` of my Windows 10 machine. I read many articles/questions with solutions like these:

- [How to have num lock enabled by default on log on screen?](https://superuser.com/q/496845/586049)
- [How to keep Num Lock ON in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1051012/586049)
- http://www.thewindowsclub.com/numlock-startup-windows-7-8
- http://www.howtogeek.com/244606/how-to-enable-num-lock-automatically-when-your-computer-boots/

And after trying them all, the only working option was disabling `Fast Startup` from `Control Panel`.

However as name suggests it is good option and I don't want to have slow startup, just because `numlock` will be enabled.

**Notice**

As I already wrote, all solutions with changing registry key **InitialKeyboardIndicators** to `2` or to `2147483650` or to `80000002` failed to work.

Also I did it for all possible folders in `HKEY_USERS` folder, not just for `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`

**Question**

I am wondering if there are any other options to enable `numlock` by default on `login screen` as it is bit annoying?

Comment: Did you try setting the value of `InitialKeyboardIndicators` to `80000002`?

Comment: @MichaelD just did it, does not work as `2` and `2147483650`.

Comment: Did you change inside every required folder? Please take a look at _Step One_ of [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/244606/how-to-enable-num-lock-automatically-when-your-computer-boots/) page. Edit: Also change the values for _ALL USERS_ not only for _.Default_.

Comment: @MichaelD yes, I did, just tried it with all possible combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Okay try the following for Win10:

- Change the value of
  *...ControlPanel/Keyboard/InitialKeyboardIndicators* to *2147483650* for
  *ALL USERS* not only for *.Default*.
- Then SHUTDOWN computer.
- Turn on computer and wait for login screen (NumLock is still off).
- Enable NUMLOCK
- SHUTDOWN computer.
- Turn on computer.

Comment: Thank you for answer and certainly what you explain works as you write, but when I continue after described steps in answer 1. Login to to windows 2. Shutdown 3. Turn on => `numlock` is disabled again. :(

Comment: Oh, I am too out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: It sounds like maybe group policy or domain policy could be rewriting the registry value.